# Does the drop-boost still exist?

Tags: mario-kart-8

With the introduction of the depressingly fast Lakitu catch for drivers that fall off the course, it has become weirdly difficult to predict exactly when you hit the ground afterwards. In most previous games, it was possible to get a boost by pressing the gas button when landing after being picked up, but since this is much harder to do now I can't really tell if it still exists or not. Does it?

Answer (score 3):

<sup>***Disclamer:** I have yet to find an answer from and official or reputable source, and I will update the answer once a more authoritative voice has spoken.*</sup>

**Short answer:** No.

I haven't seen it at all in any of my playing of the game, and according to a few topics such as [this](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/700050-mario-kart-8/69336115), it was done to offset the fact that he now rescues you much faster, often putting you a little ahead of where you originally fell off.

Comment: Which is *awesome*, by the way.